# How to style a dijit.Dialog using CSS?

Tags: css, dojo

How to add styling to a dijit Dialog using CSS? I am unable to add background-color etc to it.

```
.tundra .dijitDialog{
font-size: 12px;
background-color: #1c3664 !important;
}
```

It is not working! :-/

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/591/ !! May be you messed up with style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @import to render dojo related css then please change it to link tag. link tag will allow you to override your dojo theme css.

Comment: I am using import and am able to override the CSS.